# why not quotation mark around period

Tags: java

I am beginner in Java. As I was going through the book, I got stuck on this problem. My question is why there are single quotes instead of double quotes around this period. When we want to print a string, we use double quotes.

[image]

Comment: please add the code in the question.

Comment: single quotes represent a Character and  double quotes represent a string.

Answer (score 1):

'.' would indicate a type of char

"." would indicate a type of string

Both will work to print

Answer (score 1):

In Java, we use `''` to delimit a `char` and `""` to delimit a `String`.

In this particular case, you need a `char` because you are comparing `'.'` with the result of a call to the `charAt` method - which is always a `char`.  That is to say, `sentence.charAt(lastCharPosition)` has to be a `char`, so it can only be `'.'` and never `"."`.

If you wanted a `String`, (which you don't in this case), you could write `"."`.